# Classic ASP and ms-access: Issues with inserted data

Tags: asp-classic, ms-access-2007

I have done a webpage to insert information in a form. An Asp page retrieves this information and inserts it in a ms-access 2007 database.

In the access database there are different types of variables, like dates, numbers and strings. Here is a snapshot of the ms-access with the data filled from the form: (click to enlarge)

[image]

I have no problem when I do a query to the database using a date variable. But I have issues when I want to use the string variables.

When I do some SQL query like:

```
SELECT table.name FROM table WHERE table.city="Barcelona"
```

I do not get any result, and there are many entries with this value.

If I insert an entry manually and then I do the same query, I obtain only the last row that I added.

So there is a problem in the input variables from the asp page... Do you know what is going wrong?

Comment: I believe that using images I am helping the people to understand what I want to say, anyway, I will edit the post.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables the first image wasn't of code, it's table scheme which is relevant to the question here.

Comment: To help you we need more details: how you try to connect with the database? What is your connection string? What you mean "insert entry manually"? How are entries inserted otherwise? After adding those details please use `@` to notify so I can see and get back here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard When I say "insert entry manually" I mean, opening ms-access, clicking on the desired cell and introducing the values with the keyboard. I said "manually" to differentiate this method from the ASP-input method. 
Anyway, tired of not finding what was wrong I migrated the ms-access database to a mysql one. I changed my connection strings properly and nowadays all is working ok. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

When you're querying strings from SQL use:

```
SELECT table.name FROM table WHERE table.city='" & Variable & "'
```

SQL queries with `"` will result in an error.  If you were to run that exact query SSMS (or whatever) you would get back an error.

In your specific example, you would write:

```
SELECT table.name FROM table WHERE table.city= 'Barcelona'
```

Your SQL should use `'` instead of `"`.  In ASP `"` is interpreted differently as well.

Comment: Thank your for the reply.. but it is not working. Can I post some images that will help to understand my problem?

Comment: @MatiesPons please don't mark as accepted if it did not solve the issue, it cause people to think your problem is solved while it appears that it's not.

Comment: Can you clarify what is "not working"? @ShadowWizard is correct, if my answer did not properly solve your problem please do not mark as accepted.  Were you able to figure it out based on the above directions?

Comment: @RogueSpear00 I was not able to retrieve information that was previously inserted into the ms-access database using ASP. The data seemed to be properly inserted but when I was trying to do a query any values were returned. I had this problem only with string values, the integer and dates worked like a charm. As i said to ShadowWizard, I decided to migrate the database to a mysql one and all the problems disappeared. Thanks for your time.